# Getting ip address on macOS

Tags: macos, react-native, ip

I just got a new computer, and now `ipconfig getifaddr en1` doesn't print anything. What do I do? I need the ip address so that I can setup react native.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry about asking this question without actually doing any research. I'll go ahead and answer in case someone else has this problem.

`ipconfig getifaddr en0` finds your *wired* ip address, while `ipconfig getifaddr en1` finds your *wireless* ip address. However, if your computer is not capable of a wired connection (my new macbook doesn't have an ethernet port) then `ipconfig getifaddr en0` shows your wireless ip and `ipconfig getifaddr en1` is a no-op.

Answer (score 3):

If you guys want to find IP address without a terminal, follow these steps.

1. `CMD + Space` and search the System Preferences. Then `enter`
2. Search `Network` and press `enter`
3. Then you can able to see the IP address as shown in the attached image

[image]

Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3U99QWClBMI) and hope this would help for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple with something you can remember easily for next time. `ifconfig` works on mac/linux out of the box for most flavors and should clarify most basic network setup issues.

Answer (score -2):

if you go into the terminal and type

```
man ipconfig
```

it should work